# Recovering a deleted site page in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any type of method to recover a deleted site page in GAS?  I can certainly delete pages, I can even see that the page is deleted.  But I don't see an immediate method for page recovery.  Thanks in advance.!

Comment: You can get a reference to the deleted page by doing an advanced search:  [Google Documentation - Page Class - Search](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#search(String,Object))  Note the parameter of `includedDeleted: true`

Answer (score 0):

You can search for pages, including deleted pages, which returns an array of all pages found in the search.

[search(query, options) - Class Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#search(String,Object))

```
 var site = SitesApp.getSite("example.com", "mysite");
 var childPages = site.getChildren({
   type: SitesApp.PageType.WEB_PAGE,
   start: 0,
   max: 25,
   includeDrafts: false,
   includeDeleted: true,
   search: "target"
 });

 for(var i in childPages) {
   Logger.log(childPages[i].getName());
 }
```

Once you have a reference to that deleted page, maybe you can recreate the page.  I'm wondering if there is a way to get the deleted page into a template variable?  If you could do that, then you could create a page from the template.  Or if you could retrieve the HTML from the deleted page, you could create a page from HTML.

[Google Documentation - Create page - HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#createWebPage(String,String,String))

Oh! I just found this.  I wonder if this will work to get the HTML.

```
var page = site.getChildren()[0];
Logger.log(page.getHtmlContent());
```

Both `getChildren()` and the `search()` method return an array of `Page[]`.  So if you replace `site.getChildren()` with `search()` that might be worth trying:

```
 var site = SitesApp.getSite("example.com", "mysite");
 var childPages = site.getChildren({
   type: SitesApp.PageType.WEB_PAGE,
   start: 0,
   max: 25,
   includeDrafts: false,
   includeDeleted: true,
   search: "target"
 });

 for(var i in childPages) {
   Logger.log(childPages[i].getName());

   if (childPages[i].getName() === "deletedName") {
     Logger.log(page.getHtmlContent());
     var HTML_forRecovery = page.getHtmlContent();
     createWebPage(title, name, HTML_forRecovery);
   }
 }
```

There is a method in the Page class for checking whether a page is deleted or not:

[Class Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#isDeleted())

I don't see a method for using Apps Script to recover a deleted page:

[Apps Script Documentation for Sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app)

There is also a Sites API:

[Google Sites API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/)

But I don't see any info about recovering a deleted page.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for all you do to make StackOverflow and the world a better and more humble place.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a method for this in Apps script, so I've filed an enhancement request for it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4603&thanks=4603&ts=1418314400) (I couldn't find an existing one, but I can't imagine there wasn't one, so they might merge it with an existing issue).

I'd recommend starring it to get updates, but in the meantime I don't believe there's a workaround.